# Metal Oxide Varistor Identification / Replacement? Component marking lf9 p27z60 1803

Tags: identification, varistor

Looking for a suitable replacement or link to where I can purchase them[image]

Comment: I searched for p27z60 https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/240/Littelfuse_Varistor_ZA_Datasheet.pdf-467759.pdf

Answer (score 1):

They're made by Littelfuse. Part number [V27ZA60P](https://www.littelfuse.com/media?resourcetype=datasheets&itemid=67eb757a-126c-4f75-9f64-051f5de9b097&filename=littelfuse-varistor-za-datasheet). A 20mm low-voltage MOV.